# Bootstrap Input-Group with Spinner gives weird spinning D shape

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a weird form that will, when you select Submit, send each line of input as a separate request.  I want to put a spinner at the end of each line, which will spin until submission for that line is complete.

Technically this works without errors but instead of a nice round spinner I get this spinning "D" shape.  I've tried adding padding/margin to the beginning of the spinner but am getting nowhere.

Help please?  I'm not great with CSS.

Edit: Trying with both lastest Chrome and Brave.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="morning_metrics" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div class="form-group col-4">
      <label for="metric_sleep">Hours of Sleep </label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input id="metric_sleep" name="metric_sleep" class="form-control" type="number" />
        <div class="input-group-append spinner-border float-right">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button id="saveForm" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Set `border-radius:50%` for that spinner element

Comment: Then I'll the comment above as answer, so you could close the question, if that's ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override default styling for the spinner that was set by Bootstrap. Just set `border-radius` property to 50%.

Comment: This problem has been getting me on a loading spinner for over 9 months. On mine it worked fine on MD and above but D shaped or halved on SM or lower. Not any more, thanks.

Comment: Happy to help !

Answer (score 2):

You should add the `.rounded-circle` class to fix this.

Placing it inside an `.input-group-text` may also help.

```
<span class="input-group-text">
  <span class="spinner-border"></span>
</span>
```